# Graphs that Behave Strangely

Tags: functions, trigonometry

What exactly are $y =\cos(xy)$ or $y = x^y$? I tried graphing them on OS X grapher and the first gave me this ridiculous looking graph, with sharp angles and lines everywhere, it seemed like it was malfunctioning and $y = x^y$ gave me a more reasonable graph, but it wasn't a function like the first one (it failed the vertical line test). Can anyone give me an explanation of how you determine the graph of $y = \cos(xy)$ or $y = x^y$? Thanks!

Comment: Consider WolframAlpha (www.wolframalpha.com) for your quick graphing needs.

Comment: Are you sure those are even functions? There's no immediate reason why $y=cos(xy)$ or $y=x^y$ would only have one possible value of $y$ for each value of $x$.

Comment: Well they don't appear to be functions, but does that mean I shouldn't be able to graph them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=x^y$ is [infinite tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights), which converges for $x\in[a^b,b^a]$, with $a=\dfrac1e$ and $b=e.$ As for the other function, it's nothing else than the inverse of $x(y)=\dfrac{\arccos y}y$ , which makes sense only for $y\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks for the link! What about the other one?

Comment: @user3026053: I have no idea. :-)

Comment: Well it was worth a try, thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3026053: I've cracked the other function also! (Sorry for the delay). Some things are just **SO** simple and **SO** obvious, that we just can see them. :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks man! Very helpful and informative.